# in android extension for GAMEMAKER STUDIO cant find argfree method on extension class

Tags: java, android, game-maker-language

I am working on making a text to speech android extension for gamemaker studio, I'm getting this error: 
05-01 17:16:41.304 16939 17013 I yoyo    : Can't find argfree method on extension class:getMic []
when trying to use my extension in-game. the game doesn't crash, it just can't find anything in the extension. So what exactly is an argfree method?

I also tried tried changing the onCreate method to a public method and calling it from GM:S and several other things but no luck. Here is the relevant code, if you need more info please ask.

java class TtsStt:

```
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { //HERE is where I tried replacing
//protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
//with just public void initTTS() {...} but got same error   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tts_stt);
    preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS,0);
    editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString(TSTYLE, "military time").apply();
    RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity.findViewById(R.id.microphoneButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listen();
        }
    });
    loadQuestions();
    tts = new TextToSpeech(RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() { 
    @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                    Log.i("yoyo", "This Language is not supported");
                }
                speak("Hello");
            } else {
                Log.i("yoyo", "Initilization Failed!");
            }
        }
    });
}
public void getMic() {
            listen(); 
} 


private void listen(){
    Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Say something");
    try {
        RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity.startActivityForResult(i, 100);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
      Log.i("yoyo", "Your device doesn't support Speech Recognition");
    }
}
```

in the activity level In my manifest I have injected this:

```
<activity android:name="${YYAndroidPackageName}.TtsStt" 
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        />
    />
```

and injected the gradle dependencies in the manifest:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer was VERY unexpected, when using an extension to code between gamemaker studio and android java, if you need to use the onCreate method you must NOT write protected void onCreate( ....... ) 
Instead you have to use public void onCreate( ...... ) 
This is contrary to what is normal and expected in java and I only figured it out from reading a post about why is onCreate allways protected and saw someone's response that there is no reason to ever do otherwise, so i did otherwise and it worked!